# Python web crawler login redirects to login page

Tags: python, web-crawler, python-requests

I am currently trying to crawl a homepage that requires a login. My current code looks like this:

```
    url="xyz"

    session=requests.Session()
    mail='mail'
    password='pw'

    login_data={
        'clientid':mail,
        'key':password,
         }

    source_code=session.post('xyz_login', data=login_data)

    source_code=session.get(url)
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. It does not give an error but redirects me to the login page. The HTML of the login is the following:

```
<div><input name="clientid" style="margin:5px;width:340px;" value=""/></div>
<div style="padding:0 5px;">Password</div>

<div><input name="key" style="margin:5px;width:340px;" type="password"/></div>
<div style="padding:5px;*padding: 0 5px;">
<input type="submit" style="display:none"/>
<img id="submitButton" src="image/buttonLogin.png" alt="submit" onclick="submitForm();$('#loginForm').submit();" style="cursor:pointer;"/>
<img id="waiting" src="image/indicator.gif" alt="waiting" style="display:none"/>

<a href="Register.aspx" style="margin-left:15px"><img src="image/buttonCreateAccount.png" alt="create new Account"/></a>
```

Does someone have an idea, where the problem lies? Is it because of the submitForm()?

Comment: Really without seeing what you are trying to login to it is going to be pretty hard to say.

Comment: Might be that the site expects you to save a cookie when you log in.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the link of the homepage I try to login is the following: [link](http://doc.morningstar.com/Home.aspx)

Comment: @Tessa, do an `session.get(url)` adding a user-agent to the sessions headers then try the post, I presume you are also posting to http://doc.morningstar.com/Home.aspx?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I tried to include a user-agent, but still the same outcome `source_code=session.get(url, headers='User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0')`